# Parsing Values and splitting based on conditions in DB2 tables

Tags: sql, db2

I have 2 tables.
In the first table Table1 I have a column called DOTINCS and the values are as follows

```
PARID
1000150004
1152611254
2015620001
```

Now I have another tables DTINCS with 5 columns

```
BORO    BLOCK   LOT
------------------------
1        15       4
1     15261    1254        
2      1562       1
```

I want to join these 2 tables PARID in DOTINCS is of 10 digits and is split into 3 columns in DTINCS table by removing leading zeros. The  BORO is of 1 digit, Block 5 and Lot 4 digits.

How do I parse the PARID in such a way that Boro is 1 digit and Block I take 5 digits and take the integer portion of it and same with lot, 4 digits and only integer portion of it and exclude leading zeroes?
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made them into strings because I could. If they are stored as numbers you can cast them to strings first.

```
with vals (col1) as (
  values ('1000150004'), 
         ('1152611254'), 
         ('2015620001')
) 
select int(left(col1,1)) boro, 
       int(substr(col1,2,6)) block, 
       int(right(col1, 4)) lot 
from vals;

BORO        BLOCK       LOT        
----------- ----------- -----------
          1          15           4
          1      152611        1254
          2       15620           1

  3 record(s) selected.
```

Comment: Shouldnt `150` be `15` ??

Comment: Yeah, error in my original copy-paste that I tried to fix manually. Thanks, updated.